# Segmentation Fault using Bitmaps and Malloc

Tags: c, bitmap

I'm learning C and my assignment is to resize 24bit Bitmaps. What I have done so far:

-Correctly written code that copies and updates the Headers

-Correctly written code that resizes the Image vertically

-Padding works

I now want to have it write the resized lines to a Middleman so I can write him f times to the outfile, like so:

```
// save scanline
FILE* scanline = malloc(sizeof(bi.biWidth) * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));

// iterate over infile's scanlines
for (int i = 0, biHeight = (abs(bi.biHeight)/f); i < biHeight; i++)
{

    // iterate over pixels in scanline
    for (int j = 0; j < (bi.biWidth/f); j++)
    {
        // temporary storage
        RGBTRIPLE triple;

        // read RGB triple from infile
        fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

        for(int z = 0; z < f; z++)
        {
           // write RGB triple to outfile
           fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, scanline);                 
        }

    }

    // Add Padding to Outfile
    for (int k = 0; k < padding2; k++)
    {
        fputc(0x00, scanline);
    }

    // skip over padding, if any
    fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

    for(int s = 0; s < f; s++)
    {
        // write RGB triple to outfile
        fwrite(scanline, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
    }

}
```

My issue is (this was figured out using a debuging tool), that whenever it has to write to the scanline file I immediately get a segmentation fault.
Thank you so much in advance and I tried to make sure I'm not breaking community guidelines, but if I failed I apoligize. Have a good one!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely related to the first line of code you show

```
// save scanline
FILE* scanline = malloc(sizeof(bi.biWidth) * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
```

You have told the compiler that `scanline` is a `FILE*` (which would normally be obtained from `fopen(3)`) but instead you have assigned some uninitialized heap memory to that pointer.  When you then pass `scanline` into `fwrite(3)` and `fputc(3)` they will look for `FILE` information to tell it where to write to, but will find junk.

It is difficult to say much more as you don't show the definition of `bi` and `RGBTRIPLE` but you need to determine the correct type for `scanline` and probably change `scanline` for `outptr` in the `fwrite` and `fputc` calls.

--EDIT--

Regarding your follow up question in the comments, whether `FILE* scanline = fopen("scanline", "w")` is correct will depend on whether you want `scanline` to be a file, or a memory buffer.  In the first half of your code you seem to treat it as a file, but in the final `for` loop you are treating it as a memory buffer.

Comment: Great, I think that's it! If you wouldn't mind I only have a quick follow up. I'm now trying that line like so:                                                                      
    FILE *scanline = fopen(scanline, "w");

Comment: Great, I think that's it! If you wouldn't mind I only have a quick follow up. I'm now trying that line like so:   FILE *scanline = fopen(scanline, "w");  , this however gives me an unitialized error. Also: bi is a shortcut for Bitmapinfoheader, where things like length and width in pixels are defined, RGBTRIPLE is the pixelcolor as defined by microsofts bmp header and as both the infile and outfile are FILE* I think that should be the type for scanline. Thanks for helping, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please take a look at parameters and return type of fopen